# Finding ship grandfather took from Liverpool, England to Quebec, CA arriving January 1900?

Tags: united-states, england, ship, canada, emigration

I am hoping to find the ship that my grandfather took from Liverpool, England to Quebec, CA that arrived January 1900.

Isidore Segall's Naturalization papers give the above information. I have searched Ancestry and FamilySearch. I am unable to find record of arrival or entering at Detroit.

Would appreciate ideas for other resources that might provide evidence of arrival and/or crossing into US. Originally from Darabani, Romania and born in 1882 (possibly December 24)

Comment: Birthdate on WW! registration, Dec. 24, 1982. I believe the 1882 is correct but know that often birthdates were not always accurate

Comment: Have you checked other ports? My grandparents came to Montreal via Boston in 1903.

Comment: Here is the link to the database from Library and Archives Canada regarding immigration through the port of Quebec:

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the Library and Archives database for immigration through the port of Quebec: http://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/immigration/immigration-records/passenger-lists/passenger-lists-quebec-port-1865-1900/Pages/introduction.aspx